# New app replaces old - With different package name

Tags: android

For example, I have two apps:

com.example.free

com.example.paid

Can I specify somewhere (AndroidManifest?) that when com.example.paid is installed, com.example.free is removed, or replaced by the paid version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. A package name uniquely identifies an app.

Answer (score 1):

As @goto10 says, it is not possible. They are two different apps. I suggest you to try in app purchase. In this manner you will have just one app.

you can find more about this at [In app billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html)